# Uploading image and Validation in Yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii2, image-uploading

I'm using Yii2 to create a simple uploading image and validate images extension. I've read in Yii2 docs and I don't know `$model->validate()` always return `false`. Any idea for me?

In my Model file, I set rules for `imageFile`:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'price', 'description', 'image_path'], 'required'],
            [['price'], 'integer'],
            [['description'], 'string'],
            [['name', 'image_path'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['imageFile'], 'image', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg'],
        ];
    }
```

And in my action Index of Controller:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
    if ($model->validate() && $model->save()) {
        $model->imageFile->saveAs('uploads/' . Yii::$app->params['bonuslyRewards'] . '/' . $model->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $model->imageFile->extension);
        $model->image_path = 'uploads/' . Yii::$app->params['bonuslyRewards'] . '/' . $model->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $model->imageFile->extension;
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
    } else {
      return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: because `image_path` is required.

Comment: add `if($model->save()) {return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]); }` after `$model->image_path`.

Comment: that right, `image_path` is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remove `image_path` from the line:

```
[['name', 'price', 'description', 'image_path'], 'required'],
```

It's ok now.

Answer (score 1):

change in your controller file like....

```
 if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
 {
   $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');          
   $path=Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/your Path/';
   if(!empty($model->imageFile)){
        $model->imageFile->saveAs($path.$model->imageFile);
   }    
   if($model->save()){
      return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
   }
 }
 return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```